# Isbell duality in Joyal and Street's Introduction to Tannaka Duality

Tags: fourier-transform, duality

In Sec. 3 of Joyal and Street's [Introduction to Tannaka Duality and Quantum Groups](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/CT90Como.pdf), the authors give a commutative triangle of isomorphisms of compact topological groups (Corollary 8).  This diagram factors $\pi$ their map from a (compact topological) group $G$ to its Tannaka group $\mathcal{T}(G)$ into a map $j: G \to \mathrm{Spec}_\mathbb{R}\,R(G)$ and $\mathcal{F} : \mathrm{Spec}_\mathbb{R}\,R(G) \to \mathcal{T}(G)$.  The latter is the group Fourier transform, which is defined and studied earlier in the text.  The map $j$ enacts what (I think) is Isbell duality for the Lie group $G$.  Later on, they give the same for coset spaces $X = G/H$, as well.

Is this relationship between Isbell duality and Tannaka duality generic?  I.e., is it right to think of Tannaka duality as Isbell duality "viewed through the lens" of a Fourier transform?  Compact Lie groups have (somewhat) well understood Fourier transform, induced by their normalizable Haar measure.  Is it fair to say that this is what has allowed their duality theory to progress further than more general Lie groups?  If so, there could maybe exist other duality theories for another *non*-compact nonabelian Lie groups as long as its Fourier transform is under control.  I'm thinking of the Euclidean groups as an example.  Are there any results known about this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What are the ingredients of the instance of Isbell duality here?